# How to generate TOC of examples with package etoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

With package of `etoc` I can easily generate the list of chapters and sections using command `\tableofcontents`

Also it can generate the list tables and figures with command `\locallistoftables` and `\locallistoffigures`

```tex
\tableofcontents %   <-- line 41 in main.tex

\listoffigures %   <-- line 43 in main.tex

\listoftables % <-- line 49 in main.tex
```

But how to generate the list of all examples in the book?

For example, I have two examples in the `main.tex`, how to generate the list of all examples automaticly like the command `\listoffigures`?

```tex
\newmdenv[        % <---- line 26 in main.tex, exambox environment with `mdframed` package
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=Gray!12!White,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=Gray!12!White,
]{exambox}

%% ... omit

\begin{exambox}[frametitle=Example 1]  % <--- line 79 in main.tex
\blindtext[1]
\label{exampe1}
\end{exambox}

\begin{exambox}[frametitle=Example 2]
\blindtext[3]
\label{exampe2}
\end{exambox}
```

The mwe comes here:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{kaoboxstyle}{
    skipabove=1.5\topskip,
    skipbelow=.5\topskip,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    innerrightmargin=7pt,
    innerleftmargin=7pt,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=false,
    frametitlerule=true,
    linecolor=black,
    fontcolor=black,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright\noindent % 防止全局缩进时，标题缩进
}
\RequirePackage{etoc} % Required to insert local tables of contents


\newmdenv[
    style=kaoboxstyle,
    backgroundcolor=gray!12!white,
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!12!white,
]{exambox}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % Local scope for the following commands


% Turn on compatibility mode for the etoc package
\etocstandarddisplaystyle % "toc display" as if etoc was not loaded
\etocstandardlines % "toc lines as if etoc was not loaded

\tableofcontents % Output the table of contents

\listoffigures % Output the list of figures

% Comment both of the following lines to have the LOF and the LOT on different pages
\let\cleardoublepage\bigskip
\let\clearpage\bigskip

\listoftables % Output the list of tables

\endgroup



\chapter{First Chapter}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{fig 1}
    \label{fig:enter1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{fig 2}
    \label{fig:enter2}
\end{figure}


\chapter{Second Chapter}

\blindtext[2]

{\color{red} exambox ref: \ref{exampe1}}

\begin{exambox}[frametitle=Example 1]
\blindtext[1]
\label{exampe1}
\end{exambox}

\begin{exambox}[frametitle=Example 2]
\blindtext[3]
\label{exampe2}
\end{exambox}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{fig 3}
    \label{fig:enter3}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Third Chapter}

\blindtext
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       a  & b  \\
       c  & d
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 1}
    \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}


\chapter{Second Chapter}

\blindtext

\blindtext
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       1  & 2 \\
       3  & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table 2}
    \label{tab:table2}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [How have you made the examples?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) And how is this question related to LaTeX3? And does the question depend on usage of XeTeX?

Comment: Please don't post a link to an example. Make a *small*, *self-contained*, *compilable* document that contains *only* the code needed to show your problem.

Comment: `etoc` can only produce a list of examples if those examples are adding relevant information into the  `.toc` file see `35. Arbitrary “Lists Of...”, \etoctoccontentsline and` in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc)